# How add var to text javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost/record/FlashWavRecorder-master/jjj/r/',
   type: 'HEAD',
   error: function () {
       $('.sd').html('<img src="5-0.gif" />');
   },
   success: function () {
       bo = 'a';
       $('.sd').html('<span style="color:#99CC00; font-weight:bold;">done</span> ');
   }
});
```

I want to add varible to this part of code

```
url:'http://localhost/record/FlashWavRecorder-master/jjj/r/+var',
```

Comment: You mean you want to add some params for the ajax request?

Comment: Do what undefined said, note though, that "var" is reserved word :)

Answer (score 3):

Just append the variable like this:

```
url:'http://localhost/record/FlashWavRecorder-master/jjj/r/'+var,
```

Side-note:
Don't try to use use `var` as your variable name. That's not possible since `var` is a reserved keyword.
<sup>(But I'm sure this is just to illustrate the example)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just define a variable, and then append it in the string.

```
var someValue = "hello";
$.ajax({
 url:'http://localhost/record/FlashWavRecorder-master/jjj/r/' + someValue,
```

Answer (score 0):

Append to it like:

```
   var something = "test";
   $.ajax({
                url:'http://localhost/record/FlashWavRecorder-master/jjj/r/' + something,
```

Javascript doesn't expand variables within strings, you have to concatenate them with the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
url:'http://localhost/record/FlashWavRecorder-master/jjj/r/' + variable ,
```